# Mean and Median Vs Summary

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, mean

I'm currently doing a Reproducible Data course on Coursera and one of the questions ask for the Mean and Median of steps per day, I have this but when I confirm it with the summary function, the summary version of Mean and Median is different. I'm running this via knitr

Why would this be? 
** below is an edit showing all of my script so far including a link to the raw data:

```
##Download the data You have to change https to http to get this to work in knitr

target_url <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip"
target_localfile = "ActivityMonitoringData.zip"
if (!file.exists(target_localfile)) {
  download.file(target_url, destfile = target_localfile) 
}
Unzip the file to the temporary directory

unzip(target_localfile, exdir="extract", overwrite=TRUE)
List the extracted files

list.files("./extract")
## [1] "activity.csv"
Load the extracted data into R

activity.csv <- read.csv("./extract/activity.csv", header = TRUE)
activity1 <- activity.csv[complete.cases(activity.csv),]
str(activity1)
## 'data.frame':    15264 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ steps   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
##  $ date    : Factor w/ 61 levels "2012-10-01","2012-10-02",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
##  $ interval: int  0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...
Use a histogram to view the number of steps taken each day

histData <- aggregate(steps ~ date, data = activity1, sum)
h <- hist(histData$steps,  # Save histogram as object
          breaks = 11,  # "Suggests" 11 bins
          freq = T,
          col = "thistle1", 
          main = "Histogram of Activity",
          xlab = "Number of daily steps")


Obtain the Mean and Median of the daily steps

steps <- histData$steps
mean(steps)
## [1] 10766
median(steps)
## [1] 10765
summary(histData$steps)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##      41    8840   10800   10800   13300   21200
summary(steps)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##      41    8840   10800   10800   13300   21200
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
## Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
## [5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] knitr_1.6
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] evaluate_0.5.5 formatR_1.0    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Share your `histData`.

Comment: @Chris can you at leas show as `range(hist)` ?

Comment: perhaps a printing issue? `summary.data.frame` only shows 4 significant digits by default.

Comment: @Ben - I tried adding options(digits = 7) to the code too, but still a difference

Comment: yes, but `summary.data.frame` uses `digits = max(3, getOption("digits")-3)`, which would lead to 4 sig digits in `summary` after you set the options.  Try `summary(...,digits-7)`

Comment: @Adii_ the range(hist) comand doesn't work for me, am I taking your comment too literally?

Comment: @BenBolker - I've tried the following, but still get the same result `summary(steps, digits-7)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##      41    8840   10800   10800   13300   21200`

Comment: sorry, I meant `digits=7` (typo) -- but you've already had the question answered now ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the answers **is** correct, you just printing it wrong. You are setting `digits` option somewhere.

Put this before the scripts:

```
options(digits=12)
```

And you'll have:

```
mean(steps)
# [1] 10766.1886792
median(steps)
# [1] 10765
summary(steps)
#      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
#   41.0000  8841.0000 10765.0000 10766.1887 13294.0000 21194.0000
```

Notice that `summary` use `max(3, getOption("digits")-3)` for how many numbers is printed. So it round it a bit (10766.1887 instead of 10766.1886792).

Comment: Yes you're correct, that has worked for me also, thanks.  I'm very impressed with this site and the knowledge levels of the users, How do people get to the knowledge levels of the gurus here?

Comment: Saved me a lot of trouble!! Just to note, you can also use "digits" directly on the summary call, such as
`summary(steps, digits=5)`